# I want to add texteditor (likely markdown) in my page ,so how to embed it & from where to download it?

Tags: markdown, rich-text-editor

i have a page where users can post a question like this site , so how to add the markdown editor, or any other texteditor which has the all functions as the SO editor has . B,I,link,code,image,list etc.. thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due tinymce is "one of the most populat **WYSIWYG** editors", you can alternatively use a **markdown editor**. So users can still write plain markdown, but get additional help with these functions (B,I,link,code,image,list etc.. ) with buttons.

[lepture/editor](https://github.com/lepture/editor/) ([demo](http://lab.lepture.com/editor/)) additional shows some styles inside the markdown.

So you see `**bold**` in **`**bold**`** and `*italic*` in *`*italic*`* etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try tinymce.
http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php

Its one of the most populat WYSIWYG editors. 
Click on the "view source" tab to see its implementation.

Comment: I'm glad i could help. If you have any problems with the integration, feel free to ask :)

Comment: i checked that ,, it`s good ,, there are a lot of options available.. can it be not that simple like this editor in which you are giving me replies ,,, user has to find the add PRE tag option ,, but in this texteditor (SO) just few simlle options B,I,link,code,image,list....... i do not need more than these .. can u sort this out ..??

Comment: just remove unnecessary plugins&toolbars inside the tinymce.init(); http://i.imgur.com/gqDuhoa.png